# How to find particular value arraylist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have one array list:

```
public ArrayList GetExpenseTypes()
{
    ArrayList expArry = new ArrayList();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        string sql = "SELECT ID, TITLE";
        sql += " FROM EXPENSE_TYPE";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                expArry.Add(new ListItem(reader["TITLE"].ToString(), reader["ID"].ToString()));
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    return expArry;
}
```

My ArrayList like this

1   name1 
  2   name2 
  3   name3 
  4   name4 
  5   name6

if my value is 4 i need to display name4

How i achieve that?

Comment: Out of interest, if you are using .Net 4.0 why are you still using `ArrayList`?

Comment: `if my value is 4 i need to display name4` What you mean?

Comment: @Anandkumar I see that you are clairvoyant :)

Comment: Maybe off topic, but why? string sql = "SELECT ID, TITLE";                sql += " FROM EXPENSE_TYPE";   and not all on one line?

Comment: You should take a look at the [Dictonary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class. It might be useful for you.

Comment: why are you adding `ListItem` in your `arraylist`?

Comment: FYI: you don't need the try-catch-finally as the using will take care of closing the connection if there is an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend first changing `ArrayList` to `List<ListItem>`. If you can't do that for some reason you could use (assuming each item is unique):

```
var x = expArry.Cast<ListItem>().SingleOrDefault(exp => exp.Value == value);
if (x != null)
    //item was found
```

If you know the item will always be there just use `Single` if it will only be there once.

Comment: @Srinivas, To clarify, `IList.Cast<ListItem>` returns an `IEnumerable<ListItem>`, not a `List<ListItem>` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx. The point many of us are trying to make, is that this operation could be easily avoided by using a more modern collection type in the first place. `IDictionary<Tkey, TValue>` provides superior lookup performance to this linq statement and typed access to the data within.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ArrayList` you might want to use `Dictionary<string,string>` like this.

```
public IDictionary<string,string> GetExpenseTypes()
{
    Dictionary<string,string> expArry = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    // Your sql code

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        expArry.Add(reader["TITLE"].ToString(), reader["ID"].ToString());
    }

    // The rest of your code
}
```

Then you can get the value like this

```
var values = GetExpenseTypes();
string valueYouWant = values["4"];
```

If on the other hand your problem is that when you use the `ListItems` in a web control you are seeing the wrong values, then you need to swap the parameters when you create the `ListItem` because the first parameter is the text that is displayed and the second is the value.  Like this.

```
expArry.Add(new ListItem(reader["ID"].ToString(), reader["TITLE"].ToString()));
```

In which case you should consider using a `List<ListItem>` instead of `ArrayList`

Comment: The Id column looked like a better for `int` to me.

Comment: @Jodrell true, but I don't want to make too many assumptions, mainly wanted to point them to `Dictionary`.  I'm still wondering about why `ListItem` was being used though.

Comment: Same reason as the `ArrayList` ;-p.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `BinarySearch` method if you are searching for value types; in your case this does not seem possible.

I think you may need to use a loop assuming that you can not use `Linq` (because of the framework employed);

```
int index = -1;
for(int i=0; i<expArray.Count;i++)
{
    ListItem temp = (expArray[i] as ListItem);
    if(temp != null && temp.Value == "some value")
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ArrayList`, do something like this using a generic dictionary

```
public IDictionary<int, string> GetExpenseTypes()
{
    var result = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        var getExpenses = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT ID, TITLE FROM EXPENSE_TYPE",
            conn);

            conn.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecureReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1));
                }
            }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then you could look up your string like this

```
var type4 = GetExpenseTypes()[4];
```

---

alternatively, don't get the whole list to find one value.

```
public string GetExpenseType(int id)
{

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        var getExpenseType = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT TITLE FROM EXPENSE_TYPE WHERE ID = @p0",
            conn);

        getExpenseType.Parameters.Add(id);

        conn.Open();
        return (string)getExpenseType.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

---

If, for some bad reason, you want to stick with your `ArrayList` returning function, you can find your item like this.

```
var expenseTypes = GetExpenseTypes().OfType<ListItem>().ToDictionary(
    li => int.Parse(li.Text),
    li => li.Value);

var type4 = expenseTypes[4];
```

or, if you want to do this once.

```
var type4 = GetExpenseTypes().OfType<ListItem>()
                .Single(li => li.Text == "4").Value;
```

Comment: Is it possible bind this IDictionary to Drop Down List ID as Value & TITLE as Text

Comment: @Srinivas, as you can see on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx, an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is an `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. The properties to bind to are called `Key` and `Value`.